# Nested for do not accept a variable

Tags: twig

I've got a problem with display of this function:

```
{% for row in topics %}
        <tr align="center">
            <td class="td"><img src="{{ asset('images/tdlogo.jpg') }}" alt="Logo"></td>
            <td align="left" class="td"><a href="{{ url('topic_view', {'slug': row.idForumSection, 'id': row.idForumTopic}) }}"
                                           title="{{ row.nameTopic }}">{{  row.nameTopic  }}</td>
            {% for row in posts %}
            <td class="td">{{ row.post }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

There is a for which creates table showing forum topics, and a second for inside which is supposed to display post count for each topic. However, as it is two fors inside each other, second one iterates fully before next topic is displayed. As an affect, every topic shows all counts of topic posts from each topic.

[image]

Meanwhile, first topic should have posts:4, and second posts:1.

I tried to do something like this:

```
<td class="td">{{ posts.0.post }}</td>
```

And it works, but show first topic number of posts for all of topics.

Replacing "0" with a variable which would increase with each iteration of first "for" would work (so starting with 0, then 1, then 2, displaying numbers of posts for each topic), but i cannot make variable work inside this function.

Here is a dump of functions calling to database for variables (there are two functions, one for topics and second one for posts).

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["nameTopic"]=> string(9) "Regulamin" ["idForumSection"]=> string(1) "1" ["idForumTopic"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(3) { ["nameTopic"]=> string(13) "Administracja" ["idForumSection"]=> string(1) "1" ["idForumTopic"]=> string(1) "5" } }
```

topics:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["nameTopic"]=> string(9) "Regulamin" ["idForumSection"]=> string(1) "1" ["idForumTopic"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(3) { ["nameTopic"]=> string(13) "Administracja" ["idForumSection"]=> string(1) "1" ["idForumTopic"]=> string(1) "5" } }
```

posts:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["idForumTopic"]=> string(1) "1" ["idForumSection"]=> string(1) "1" ["post"]=> string(1) "4" } [1]=> array(3) { ["idForumTopic"]=> string(1) "5" ["idForumSection"]=> string(1) "1" ["post"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

Please, help me!

Comment: Restructure your data first...